# Scraping data from a website with Simple HTML Dom

Tags: php, html, screen-scraping, scraper, simpledom

I work to finish an API for a website (https://rushwallet.com/) for github.

I am using PHP and attempting to retrieve the wallet address from this URL: https://rushwallet.com/#n3GjsndjdCURphhsqJ4mQH7AjiXlGI.
Can anyone can help me?

My code so far:

```
$url = "https://rushwallet.com/#n3GjsndjdCURphhsqJ4mQH7AjiXlGI";

$open_url = str_get_html(file_get_contents($url));

$content_url = $open_url->find('span[id=btcBalance]', 0)->innertext;
die(var_dump($content_url));
```

Comment: That address is loaded through javascript so it doesn't exist in the DOM when you load the page through Simple HTML DOM.

Comment: The `n3GjsndjdCURphhsqJ4mQH7AjiXlGI` is a key to access the wallet, its not an address, how do you think that will work? Are you going to ask the users to give you their key? And trust you not to simply move their coins? All that site is doing is using blockchains json api.

Comment: Lawrence Cherone you don't think. I need wallet not acces, wallet is showed in page. If you are blind please: exit;

Answer (score 0):

You cannot read the correct content in this case. You are trying to access the non-rendered page content. Therefore, you always read the empty string. The content is loaded after the page is fully loaded. The page source is shown as:

```
฿<span id="btcBalance"></span>
```

If you want to scrape the data in this case, you need to use rendering engine which is possible to render javascript. One possible engine is [phantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/), which is a headless browser and able to scrape the data after rendering.

Comment: You can give me a tutorial for that?

Comment: This is your work. Please google it, you search `phantomjs scrape` and find many tutorials. phantomJS is fully documented and you should try to learn in their official site too.